# jQuery Mobile - Toolbar Ellipsis in iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile

I am rendering HTML locally in an iPad app using jQuery Mobile. The titles are getting "..." ellipses in them, even though there is lots of room. I am using off-the-shelf JQM and JQM CSS classes.

How can I tell JQM to render the full title?

Below is a screen shot with some blue markup.

Here's the Title:

```
`<div data-role='header' data-position='inline'>
       <h1>the long title goes here</h1></div>`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h1` tag gets margin applied that you can overwrite so the title won't get clipped so much.

```
.ui-page .ui-header h1 {
    margin-left  : 0;
    margin-right : 0;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ubYWU/

Note that you will want to give `left`/`right` `margin` values that make it so your title won't overlap with your icon(s).

Answer (score 1):

The combination of setting overflow:hidden and text-overflow:ellipsis is what is causing that  Override the ui-title then play with the margin to try and center. They probably include this to make room for buttons in the header and footer. Try this:

```
.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title {
    overflow:visible;
    margin: .6em 20%;
}
```

JQM 1.1-RC1's default left and right margin was set at 30% for this. Just adjust it till it fits your needs.

UPDATE: I added the version that used the 30% default. Thanks Jasper.

Comment: jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 and older declares this CSS for `.ui-title`: `margin: .6em 90px .8em;`. jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC-1 is the first milestone that uses `30%` for the `left`/`right` `margin` properties. You can see this by looking at the docs for each version.

Answer (score 1):

It's also important to note you should add a "line-height:" to your elements so in case they wrap they will not land on top each other on line 2